# Rails: Size is not working on a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models, Student and Absence, with the relationship:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :absences

class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
```

I want to see how many absences have been logged for each student, and show that total on the student's #show page. In the console, I'm able to query this by calling:

```
a = Student.find(1)
a.absences.size
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work in the app itself. Would the preferred way of querying this in the app be in the model or the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work, since you are calling association on the model, not instance. At first you should fetch a student and then count associated records:

```
Student.find(<id here>).absences.size
```

To aggregate this information for all students, you can add `absence_count` attribute accessor in `Student` model:

```
attr_accessor :absence_count
```

and then do something like this:

```
Student.includes(:absences).each{|s| s.absence_count = s.absences.size}
```

If you just need to output it in the view, then you can try the following:

```
Student.includes(:absences).each do |student|
  puts student.absences.size
end
```

Comment: You're right. I should have said that when I got it to work in the Console, I was querying an instance of the Student model. I will update my question to clarify that.

Comment: @kongzi: post the desired result output

Comment: Desired result output would be to show, for each Student, their number of Absences.

Comment: @kongzi: You've given a vague answer to the question,still, check updated post.